Newspaper-inspired website content get aged over time everyday
I've came up with a concept for my newspaper-inspired website:  the idea is for the site to appear fresh and pristine at midnight, then gradually look more aged, dimmed, and worn-out as the day progresses, resetting back to 'new' at the start of each day. The aging would include reducing opacity, adding filters (blue, sepia, contrast) and possibly a crumpled paper texture for backgrounds.
Do you think it could be too distracting for users?
I was thinking about adding a circular area around the cursor that would 'reveal' the original content looking (original background color, image's real appearance, etc.) for desktop and a 'refresh' button for mobile.
Are there any potential UX pitfalls you foresee with the gradual ‘aging’ effect? Would love to hear your thoughts on how this might impact overall usability and brand perception!

I understand the cursor is used as a pointer to reveal the original content. I think people would feel frustrated because reading the newspaper during the fresh period is uncomplicated. While the aging effect could prove interesting ,users who read one story and binge-read the rest will feel "What has happened to the website?". However, the aging effect can also be tiring in user experience due to increased steps just to read an article and most who read the newspaper are going to scan the news rather than read everything offered within the article unless it's their cup of tea.

Your point makes sense, thank you!
